# How can I determine if two 3d edges are identical?

Tags: c++, edge-detection

I'm trying to detect the silhouette edge of a 3d object. I know that you must first determine weather a face is looking at a position then find the edges that are shared between front and back facing.

I've been able to figure out front and back facing things but I can't figure out how to find if the edges are being shared without a lot of if statements. My vertex data is stored from x1,z1,y1,x2,z2,y2,x3,z3,y3 for every polygon.

Comment: Are you asking how to determine if two line segments are on the same line?

Comment: @Code-Guru Not exactly, if 2 line segments are the same line.

Comment: @BlueSpud don't use the term "line" without qualification to make yourself less ambiguous.  "if 2 line segments are the same segment" would confuse people less.  :)  ... so, what have you tried?  Do you have a "line segment" class?  Did you sort the begin/end points so that the (lexically) lower one is always `first`?  From reading your description, your polygons are actually triangles -- is this true?

Comment: @Yakk All I've tried is about 36 if statements, and that seemed to work but its horribly slow, and for real time rendering, its not great. I don't exactly have a line segment class, I have a vector filled with structs of polygons. The points are sorted as x1,z1,y1,x2,z2,y2,x3,z3,y3 and loaded from a .obj file, so I have no idea what order they're in. Yes, the polygons are triangles.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to determine if two line segments are on the same line, you can use a little bit of Euclidean geometry. Let's cover a couple of definitions:

A *point* A is an n-tuple `(a1, a2, ..., an)` of real numbers. In the 3D case, `n=3`.

*Scalar multiplication* of a point A and a real number `t` is defined as

```
tA = (t*a1, t*a2, ..., t*an)
```

With these two ideas, we can represent a line very easily. For two points `A` and `B`, the point `P` which satisfies the equation

```
P = tA + (1-t)B
```

is on the line `AB` where `t` is a real number.

When `0 <= t <= 1`, `P` lies between `A` and `B` with `P=A` when `t=1` and `P=B` when `t=0`.

Now to put this into a programming perspective, you can create two classes: `Point` and `Line`. Using the equation given above, it is very easy to determine if a `Point` lies on a given `Line`. To determine if two line segments are on the same line, simply use the two `Point` which define one `Line` and check if they lie on the other `Line`.

Comment: Again, I need to check if two lines are exactly the same, the same position, everything.

Answer (score 0):

> if 2 line segments are the same line

Two line segments are the same if they use identical point coordinates or identical point indexes. Testing whether they are ON the same line is entirely different problem that you don't need to solve in order to find silhouette.

1. Use indexed primitives.
2. Precalculate list of edges and required topology tables in advance, while loading model.
3. **IF you're trying to draw a shadow, use shadowmaps instead** - they're much simpler to comprehend.

Indexed primitives mean that
1. you store all points in array (`std::vector<vector3> points;` or something similar, where `vector3` is datatype that store xyz coordinates), and every point is unique.
2. faces and edges refer to to points using integer point indexes.

I.e.

```
struct Vec3{
    float x, y, z;
};

typedef unsigned int Index;

struct Face{
    enum{vertsPerFace=3};
    Index verts[vertsPerFace];
};

struct Edge{
    enum{vertsPerEdge=2};
    Index verts[vertsPerEdge];
};
```

When you load model, you build list of points and convert all faces into indexed primitives using `std::set` `std::map` or similar structures. Once you have indexed primitves, you can build associative tables (using std::map) that would map edge to the list of faces `std::multimap<std::pair<Index, Index>, FaceIndex>`, map edges to the faces indexes that use those edges `std::map<std::pair<VertexIndex, VertexIndex>, FaceIndex>` and so on.